# Magento: Display block after category description

Tags: magento

I’ve a problem to place a block right after the category description on a category page.

I’ve got a separated layout xml file for a new filtered navigation. The xml is:

```
 <catalog_category_layered> 
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
    <remove name="enterprisecatalog.leftnav"/> 
    <reference name="left">
       <block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view" name="amshopby.navleft" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view_top" name="amshopby.navtop" before="-" template="amshopby/view_top.phtml"/>
            <block type="amshopby/top" name="amshopby.top" before="category.products" template="amshopby/top.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

So it’s this line which places this block at the beginning of the content area of my category page:

```
<block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view_top" name="amshopby.navtop" before="-" template="amshopby/view_top.phtml"/>
```

So now my category page looks like this:

filtered navigation -> category title -> category description -> product overview

But I’d like to rearrange it so that it looks like

category title -> category description -> filtered navigation -> product overview

But how I can place this block after the description? It’s a new block which includes the title, description, products etc.:

(standard catalog.xml)

```
 <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left"></reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

I really have no idea how to add this block after the category description.  I’m new to magento and the block system is quiet confusing. I’ve tried things like

```
<block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view_top" name="amshopby.navtop" before="product_list_toolbar" template="amshopby/view_top.phtml"/>
```

But this doesn’t work. I also tried to add this block code in catalog.xml but then it's not shown.

Does anybody has an idea what I can do? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What I'd advise that, filter navigation (aka layered navigation) is part of Left section. You need to remove it from left and add inside the `content`section in catalog.xml Find the line `<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>` in `magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`.
After if condition call `$this->getChildHtml('amshopby.navtop')`.
This should work. But with Experience you'll be needing few more tweaking

Answer (score 3):

In `amshopby.xml`, cut the following lines of XML:

```
<block type="amshopby/catalog_layer_view_top" name="amshopby.navtop" before="-" template="amshopby/view_top.phtml"/>
<block type="amshopby/top" name="amshopby.top" before="category.products" template="amshopby/top.phtml"/>
```

Then in `catalog.xml`, paste those two lines here:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
<!-- ... -->
<reference name="content">
<!-- ... -->
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">

<!-- paste XML here -->

<!-- ... -->
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Then in `template/catalog/category/view.phtml` paste in this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('amshopby.navtop'); ?>
```

After the following:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I try this, nothing from the amshopby block is shown.

There is no error, just empty space.

Comment: Did you paste those two lines of XML after the `category.products` block? I've done this for a store I'm working on using the Improved Navigation module and it's working well.